# In Android, having a file descriptor, how can you open a file with fopen in the C NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Having obtained a file URI from a file picker (based on this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files)  in Android, I am now trying to open that file from the NDK in C with the fopen function. I am able to access the "file descriptor" with the following code:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getActivity().getContentResolver().
            openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
pfd.getFileDescriptor();
```

I am unclear what the file descriptor is. Can I obtain the file path from that?

Will the C code also have the permission granted to read the file? The documentation states that the URI obtained is granted permission without any additional permissions: "Because the user is involved in selecting the files or directories that your app can access, this mechanism doesn't require any system permissions".

So, how would one, knowing the file descriptor be able to get the file path and then use it in fopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the file descriptor for unix from the Java code and then pass it to the native code the following way:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
                            openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                    int f = pfd.detachFd();
```

It won't work with getFD();
You can then use fdopen or write functions in the native code.